# How to configure proxy if dependency tries to download from internet?

Tags: git, go, proxy

I have GoLang

```
go version go1.10.3 windows/amd64
```

In our corporate network access to internet only via Proxy.

in git client did set

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy:8118
```

It did work for this one

```
c:\go\bin\go get -u -v github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus
```

BUT if in new pkg did have a dependency for example

```
C:\Windows\system32>c:\go\bin\go get -u -v github.com/prometheus/common/log
github.com/prometheus/common (download)
github.com/sirupsen/logrus (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal?go-get=1: dial tcp 193.184.73.141:4
43: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
package golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal
" (https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal?go-get=1: dial tcp 193.184.73.141:443:
connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog?go-get=1: dial tcp 193.184.73.
141:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
package golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/sys/windows/sv
c/eventlog" (https fetch: Get https://golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog?go-get=1: dial tcp 193.1
94.173.141:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
.)
Fetching https://gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2?go-get=1: dial tcp 135.186.143.184:443
: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
package gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2" (h
ttps fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2?go-get=1: dial tcp 135.186.143.184:443: connec
tex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
```

How to configure proxy if a dependency tries to download from internet?

Comment: Go respects the usual environment variables by default: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyFromEnvironment

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the http_proxy environment as you did for git.

Try running `set http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:8118` and then run the `go get` command

Comment: I did set set http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:8118 and after go get, some of one did not install and returned error - https fetch failed: Get https://gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2?go-get=1. If didn't use proxy - all working.

Comment: maybe you need to set https_proxy also? Question though, how does `go get` work if no proxy is set, how are you bypassing the proxy?